# strtotime() not able to handle 02/29?

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I calculate the amount of days between two dates like this:

```
                    $start = strtotime($_SESSION['sdate']); 
                    $end = strtotime($_SESSION['hdate']); 
                    echo ($end - $start); 
                    $duration = ($end - $start) / 3600 /24; 
                    $duration+=1; //plus one day 
                    echo " The ad will show for ".$duration." day(s)<br/>";
```

Which generally works fine but things seem to mess up when I have a 
start sdate of 2012-02-29 and an hdate of 2012-04-01. I get a duration 
of: 32.9583333333 
Why is this? That's messing up my calculations. Is there a better way 
to do this? 
Thanks! 
Ron

Comment: It's not like you can't round it up to full days...

Comment: may be your server timezone is not updated. check that. :)

Comment: Rather strange. Looks like for everything past Feb 29, every day is only 23 hours.

Comment: It is nothing much to do with 2012-02-29; it is due to the change from standard time to daylight saving time which occurs in the USA on the second Sunday in March (2012-03-11, for example).  That day is 1 hour shorter than the rest, leaving the calculation correct but confusing.  The converse problem will occur when the time changes from daylight saving to standard time, which happens on the first Sunday in November in the USA, or 2012-11-04 for example.  It is sufficient to round to the nearest whole number to get the days between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it is because of the DST time change, which occurs on the last Sunday of March.

Comment: This is the reason. Easily fixed by just using: `$start = new DateTime("04/01"); echo $start->diff(new DateTime("02/29"))->days;`

Comment: When the change between standard and daylight saving time occurs varies by country.  In the USA, it is now the second Sunday in March, and has been since 2007.  In Europe, it is the first Sunday in April.

Answer (score -1):

Your server timezone is not updated. That's why it is creating the problem.